# thumbor // url syntax to crop and apply filter at the same time

Tags: thumbnails, image-resizing, thumbor

For the ones that uses it, if it is ever possible

Looking though the docs, can't find a clue about building an url that would crop the image and apply a filter at the same time

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing, the syntax would be like this:

```
http://<your_thumbor_server>/unsafe/<crop>/filters:<some_filter>/<image_source_url>
```

Which might look something like this:

```
http://thumborhost.com/unsafe/200x0:600x800/filters:format(webp)/http://imagehost.com/path/to/source.jpg
```

The full url syntax as stated by the Thumbor docs is:

> http://*thumbor-server*/hmac/trim/AxB:CxD/fit-in/-Ex-F/HALIGN/VALIGN/smart/filters:FILTERNAME(ARGUMENT):FILTERNAME(ARGUMENT)/*image-uri*

Docs: http://thumbor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html